# What is the meaning of spoiler?

Tags: discussion, spoilers

I came across this word on this site. I posted one sci-fi question and many people started to downvote my question and called it a spoiler.

What does "spoiler" mean, and why is it causing people to downvote questions?

Comment: [Google got me to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoiler_(media))

Comment: No.. I am serious.. I want to give away my reputation points... This was the only way I share my points...

Comment: Thanks Izkata.. I have started bounty for 2 other questions.. But I am not able to start for this one.. I want to award you the bounty.. Please post your comment as answer....

Comment: I have edited your question to focus on the actual question. The complaints about the community and your comments about your plans for your account/reputation aren't particularly productive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spoiler is a piece of information that gives away ([spoils](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spoil)) important plots and/or information that would be of interest to someone who has not read/watched the book/film, but would like to.

For example - Jesus dies but is resurrected, or that the Big Bad Wolf eats Little Red Riding Hood, but the huntsman saves her in the end...

Comment: Additionally I would add that spoilers pertain to a  surprise that the author of a given work planned for the audience. Best example is Bruce Willis at the end of The Sixth Sense. So by telling people something they don't know yet, you have literally "spoiled the surprise".

Comment: What?!?! the huntsman saves her in the end? thanks for spoiling that for me!! :)